# GCP oauth consent screen - Domain Verification for amazoncognito.com

Tags: flutter, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

We are using SignIn with Google on our Flutter App that uses AWS cognito. Recently it started giving error:

```
"Error 403: access_denied The developer hasn’t given you access to this app. It’s currently being tested and it hasn’t been verified by Google. If you think you should have access, contact the developer"
```

The app was in "Testing" and seems to have reached the limit of 100 users. In order to have more than 100 users use the SignIn with Google option, we need to put the Google Authentication App to "Production". In order to do that Google is asking for domain verification of the amazoncognito.com used in "Authorized redirect URIs". Since we don't own this domain we can't verify it.

Can someone please help with how can we get the verification of the GCP "oauth consent screen" done with other domains like amazoncognito.com?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible.

Your best bet would be to file a feature request with Google for a supported verification progress for third-party user identity services.

I would suggest using the [Google Workspace add-ons](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392207) component for this type of request.